# How to conditionally export utility functions etc from a large set only when needed

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, export, es6-modules

I have a large utilities module, utils.js, that has a mix of vanilla JS exports and dom related exports (use of Canvas, for example).

I'd like to avoid importing the dom utilities when running outside the browser's main thread .. in workers and deno for example.

One solution would be to only export dom functions while in the browser's main thread. Unfortunately this doesn't work due to exports having to be top level, thus
if( inDom ) export function ...
is an error.

Also, trying to wrap the code in try-catch doesn't work correctly in deno because it error-checks imports while loading, unlike in the browser.

So I've broken the utils.js into two files, jsUtils.js and
domUtils.js. I'd like to keep the original utils.js name but which simply always exports jsUtils.js, and domUtils.js conditionally when in the browser's main thread.

This should be as simple as:

> ```
> const inDom = typeof document !== undefined
> export * from './jsUtils.js'
> if( inDom ) export * from './domUtils.js'
> ```

.. but naturally this fails, the second export is not top level.

So my question is: How can I have a utils.js which always includes jsUtils.js and domUtils.js only when inDom?

Comment: You can't do conditional static imports or exports.  That's a rule of ES6.  You can do dynamic imports only with the dynamic version of `import` (the one that is asynchronous and returns a promise).

Comment: Why not just split the utils module into browser and non-browser stuff.   Then, you can import the one that is appropriate for the environment you're writing code for.